# how to save sudo vim /sbin/chkconfig

Tags: command-line, vim

I am following the steps of oracle installation in this site http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.ca/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html.

I don't know how to save the file.

Typing a command like  command `sudo vim /sbin/chkconfig` is opening a nano text editor.
So how to save that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening the file with vim, not with nano. After editing the file press escape to exit the Insert-Mode. Then try `:wq` to write an exit the editor.

Comment: what's the difference between the two commands we each offered? Just out of curiosity

Comment: There is no difference between `:wq` and `:x`. The result is the same. I'm just used to use `:wq`.

Comment: Fair enough, likewise I'm used to using `:x` Thank you for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

By typing vim you have opened it in Vim not nano as your question states, nano is slightly more user friendly than vi editors, I've found.

However, you can save files in vim using `:x`, if you're in "Insert" mode you will have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> first.

Comment: thanks it works for me.but what mean the encrypt key?

Comment: That's if you use `:X` not `:x`. The difference is the case. If you use capital X it will encrypt the file, with the password you enter. In this case I presume you want small x which will save and close the editor.

Comment: You should mark one as an answer, even though they're the same.